# Probability that $n$ vectors of a binary superimposed code will have $k$ collisions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, coding-theory

I was reading a pre-print (https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10102) and in this paper they discuss collisions, which is defined as when two or more binary vectors of a superimposed code contain a $1$ in the same position across the multiple vectors.

So my question is how would one determine the probability that $n$ vectors will have $k$ collisions?

The paper discusses $2$ errors causing $1$ collision in a superimposed code of finite size, but it does not discuss the probability that a collision occurs. I want to explore this further, and so I am trying to find the probability that $n$ vectors in a superimposed code of arbitrary size will have $3$ collisions, and then generalize to $k$ collisions.

My work so far has been noting that the probability that any $n$ number of vectors will have three $1$s in the same position is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-3}$ and then trying to expand that to a Poisson distribution,

$$P\left(X=3\right)=\frac{\mu^{x}e^{-\mu}}{x!}=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{3!}=0.01263$$.

Any input, feedback, or advice, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you point to *where* in the paper 2 collisions is discussed?

Comment: In figure 1 it shows 2 errors, 1 collision. I’m trying to find the probability that any collisions occurs, 3 was just a number pulled out of a hat. I don’t think the paper specifically mentions the probability of collisions occurring, it just mentions collisions.

Comment: I apologize it’s figure 2.